# How to scrape table from a web using Python (BeautifulSoup)?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table, scrape

I am trying to extract table from a website. I've been using BeautifulSoup, but in the end I got the empty rows on the table I **scraped**.

```
#import package
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#to get the html of the page
req = Request('https://covid19.go.id/peta-risiko', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
type(soup)

# Get the title
title = soup.title
print(title)

# Print out the text
text = soup.get_text()
print(soup.text)

#to extract all the hyperlinks within the webpage
soup.find_all('a')

#use a for loop and the get('"href") method to extract and print out only hyperlinks
all_links = soup.find_all("a")

#To print out table rows only, pass the 'tr' argument in soup.find_all()
for link in all_links:
    print(link.get("href"))

# Print the first 10 rows for checking
rows = soup.find_all('tr')
print(rows[:10])
```

I get `[]` when I print the first 10 rows. I don't know it could happen. Is it because of the table consists multiple page (page 1, 2, 3, next page, etc)?.

Any solutions for **scraping** this table on this web? [Web page](https://covid19.go.id/peta-risiko). I want to get a table with columns : PROVINSI, KOTA/KABUPATEN, STATUS

Comment: Instead of using ``Bs4`` try using the json exposed via the the API which powers the table data, ``https://data.covid19.go.id/public/api/skor.json``

Comment: FYI it's __scraping__ and __scraped__ not scrapping or scrapped. 'scrapping' means  throwing away like rubbish, or fighting :-(

Comment: This is because the content is embedded in an **iframe**. iframe displays this [page](https://data.covid19.go.id/public/zonasi_resiko.html). The data in this page is fetched using this [API](https://data.covid19.go.id/public/api/skor.json) as mentioned by @sushanth

Comment: @sushanth thank you,  for  https://data.covid19.go.id/public/api/skor.json this works for me.